# jQuery ajax call and globalEval

Tags: ajax, jquery

I was using the following in an jQuery ajax call just fine with 1.5.1, but since upgrading to jQuery 1.6.2 this globalEval function stops the success function dead in it's tracks. Anybody know why? Or some alternative code that would achieve the same thing?

> success: function(data){ 
>   ...
>       $(data).filter('script').each(function(){
>           $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
>       }); 
>   ... 
>   }

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers and for all AJAX calls?

Comment: Yes it is happening in all browsers and for all calls

Answer (score 0):

Try using 1.6.1. JQuery team noted some Ajax quirks with the latest version and will likely be patching those in 1.6.3

Comment: Thanks AlienWebguy, but unfortunately I already tried that and still had the same issue. :(